# Viewing an integral as an expected value

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Let $\omega\in (0,1]$ be represented in binary as $\omega=0.d_1(\omega)d_2(\omega)\cdots$ where each $d_i(\omega)$ is either $0$ or $1$ (a tail of zeros is prohibited). We define $r_n(\omega)=2d_n(\omega)-1$ and $s_n(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i(\omega)$.

We may use $(r_n)$ to model a simple random walk: Pick a $\omega\in(0,1]$. There is a particle initially at the origin. At the $i$th stage, where $i=1,2,3,\cdots$ the particle moves a unit to the right or left depending on whether $r_i(\omega)$ is $1$ or $-1$ respectively. Clearly, $s_n(\omega)$ represents the position of the particle after $n$ steps.

It is proved in [my book](https://g.co/kgs/9Afm7B) that $\int_0^{1}s_n(\omega)d\omega=0$. I understand that proof. After that there is a line:

> If the integral is viewed as an expected value, then $\int_0^1s_n(\omega)d\omega=0$ says that the mean position after $n$ steps of a
>   random walk is $0$.

I don't understand this line. I interpret $s_n$ as a sum of $n$ independent RVs which have identical two-point uniform distributions. As such $s_n$ is discrete and its expected value should be given by a summation. The book has not mentioned either random variables or expected value till this point. Can someone explain this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the case where $X$ is a discrete random variable, eg. it takes its values in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. There are in general *two* ways to express the expectation of a random variable of the form $f(X)$, where is $f$ a (deterministic) function, say from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,m\}$:

(1) $\mathbf{E} f(X)=\sum_{y=1}^m y \mathbf{P}[f(X)=y]$
(2) $\mathbf{E} f(X)=\sum_{x=1}^n f(x) \mathbf{P}[X=x]$

(1) is basically the definition of the expectation of a random variable (applied to $f(X)$). (2) follows from (1) by an easy theorem that we sometimes call *transfert formula* (it's so easy that we usually don't mention it).

Now in your case, the variable $X$ is called $\omega$ and it's a continuous random variable. The formula (1) still makes sense:

$$\mathbf{E} s_n(\omega)=\sum_{i=-n}^n i \mathbf{P}[s_n(\omega)=i]$$

However, to write (2), you now need an integral because the underlying measure is not discrete anymore:

$$\mathbf{E} s_n(\omega)=\int_{0}^1 s_n(t) \,dt$$

Comment: What is the pdf for $\omega$?

Comment: @Shahab: $\omega$ follows a uniform distribution over $(0,1]$, so its pdf is 1 on $(0,1]$ and 0 elsewhere. It makes sense to look at the last equality as $\mathbf{E} s_n(\omega)=\int_0^1 s_n(\omega)\times 1 \,d\omega$

Comment: Honestly it is a bit confusing to use $\omega$ both as a random variable and as an index in the integral. I will change this

Comment: Thanks. I have a small additional doubt. You are essentially saying that $s_n\circ \omega$ is a continuous RV. What is its PDF?

Comment: @Shahab: $s_n \circ \omega$ is *not* continuous (let alone because all its mass is contained in $\mathbf{Z}$), it has no PDF (wrt Lebesgue measure). The "real" formula for $\mathbf{E} s_n \circ \omega$ is the first one (with the sum). But there is no contradiction in the fact that there exists *some* integral formula to compute the expectation of a discrete random variable

Comment: Thanks, understood. BTW what you call the "transfert formula" (is the spelling correct?) is also known as the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).