# Proving that two RVs are uncorrelated

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, correlation

(See also related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631881/viewing-an-integral-as-an-expected-value))

Let $\omega\in (0,1]$ be represented in binary as $\omega=0.d_1(\omega)d_2(\omega)\cdots$ where each $d_i(\omega)$ is either $0$ or $1$ (a tail of zeros is prohibited). We define $r_n(\omega)=2d_n(\omega)-1$.

We may use $(r_n)$ to model a simple random walk: Pick a $\omega\in(0,1]$. There is a particle initially at the origin. At the $i$th stage, where $i=1,2,3,\cdots$ the particle moves a unit to the right or left depending on whether $r_i(\omega)$ is $1$ or $-1$ respectively.

It is proved in [my book](https://g.co/kgs/9Afm7B) that $\int_0^{1}r_i(\omega)r_j(\omega)d\omega=0$ for $i\ne j$. I understand that proof. After that they say that:

> (This equation) corresponds to the fact that independent random variables are uncorrelated.

I don't understand this line.

To show $X=r_i(\omega)$ and $Y=r_j(\omega)$ to be uncorrelated (note that $\omega$ is uniform in $(0,1]$), I would prefer showing $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. Now, I can prove that $E(X)=\int_0^1 (r_i(t)\times 1) dt=0$ and similarly $E(Y)=0$. So, it remains to prove that $E(XY)=0$. I don't know the PDF of $XY$ or $(X,Y)$ however. Moreover somewhere the equation $\int_0^{1}r_i(\omega)r_j(\omega)d\omega=0$ has to be used. Can someone explain how to find $E(XY)$?

Comment: What does the "law of the unconscious statistician" give you for $E(XY)$?

Comment: The way I understand the law is that  $E(g\circ X)$ is $\int g(x)f(x)dx$ where  $f$ is the PDF of $X$. So, what should $g$ be so that $g\circ \omega=(r_i\circ\omega)(r_j\circ \omega)$?

Comment: Can we say $g(x)=r_i(x)r_j(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Underlying is probability space $(\Omega=(0,1],\mathcal B(0,1],P)$ where $\mathcal B(0,1]$ denotes the collection of Borel subsets of $(0,1]$ and $P$ is the restriction of Lebesguemeasure $\lambda$ on $(0,1]$.

In that situation the expectation of a random variable $Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is defined as:$$\int Z(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int_0^1Z(\omega)d\omega$$ where on RHS there is integration wrt the Lebesgue measure.

---

If $X$ is prescribed by $\omega\mapsto r_i(\omega)$ and $Y$ is prescribed by $\omega\mapsto r_j(\omega)$ then **by definition**: $$\mathbb EXY=\int_0^1r_i(\omega)r_j(\omega)d\omega$$ Since moreover $\mathbb EX=0=\mathbb EY$ here we also have:$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\int_0^1r_i(\omega)r_j(\omega)d\omega$$
So the fact that it takes value $0$ tells us exactly that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: No small part of my difficulty lies in the fact that the book has not defined expectation yet. So I am recalling the definitions I leaned ages ago. Can you please tell me the complete definition of $E(g(X,Y))$. The way I recalled it was as $\int\int g(x,y) f(x,y)dxdy$ where $f(x,y)$ is the joint PDF.

Comment: Formal definition is $\int g(X(\omega),Y(\omega)P(d\omega)$ where $P$ is the probability on the underlying [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition). What you recall is actually a theorem. It states that the expectation can also be found on base of the *distribution* of $(X,Y)$. It is named as [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).